# C : Debugging & Run - Different Output

Tags: c

i'm using code-blocks 16.01 when i debug this code it show me a correct output but when i run it it show incorrect output! how to solve this?

```
int main()
{
    char ch[100],var[100],val[100],tempVa[100];
    int i = 0,j=0,count=0;
    while (1)
    {
        puts("Enter the expression (or (end) to exit):");
        gets(ch);
        if (strcmp(ch, "end") == 0 || strcmp(ch, "END") == 0)
            exit(-1);
        else if(2 == sscanf(ch,"%s = %s", var, val))
        {   i = 0;
            printf("Variable is : %s\t Value Before evaluating : %s\n",var, val);
            while (i<=strlen(val))
            {
                while (val[i]!='-'&&val[i]!='%'&&val[i]!='/'&&val[i]!='*'&&val[i]!='+'&&i<strlen(val))
                    tempVa[j++]=val[i++];

                i++;
                for (count=0; count<strlen(tempVa); count++)
                    printf("%c", tempVa[count]);
                for (count=strlen(tempVa); count>=0; count--)
                    tempVa[count]='\0';
                j=0;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Smaple Input** : Hassan = Merna+Mohamed+Ahmed

Debugging Output[image: Debug]

Run Output
[image: Run]

From where does those garbage come?!

Comment: Your images are not working. Could you write the output in text format?

Comment: hint: you need to null-terminate `tempVa` after you copy contents into it.  In debug, it is likely zeroed out at start, but in release, it's just whatever's in the memory at the time.

Comment: @ErikW 
Run : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmR5e.png
Debug : MernaMohamedAhmed

Comment: @Joe` for (count=strlen(tempVa); count>=0; count--)
                    tempVa[count]='\0';` i already Nulled it here i think.

Comment: Another pic of Run, sometimes it works, some times it doesn't work .. i don't know what is the reason :(
[link](http://i.imgur.com/qtjFjza.png)

Comment: Change this `while(val[i]!=''&&val[i]!='%'&&val[i]!='/'&&val[i]!='*'&&val[i]!='+'&&i<strlen(val))` to this: `while(i<strlen(val) && val[i]!=''&&val[i]!='%'&&val[i]!='/'&&val[i]!='*'&&val[i]!='+')`.

Comment: This way you will always check only within the length of the val.

Comment: @Arash , but i want to remove All operations (+-/*%) in new string .. that's what i aim for.

Comment: 'i don't know what is the reason' - it's UB.  Get rid of the images - they're annoying and unwanted on SO.

Comment: You call `strlen(tempVa)` when you have not null-terminated `tempVa`. You could use `j` instead of the strlen call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works
Edits:

1. You should import the string.h library (anyways, you should always resolve any warning you have).
2. Use return -1, that is why main is an int function.
3. Like @joe said in the comments, you should always terminate your string with '\0'.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // edit

int main()
{
    char ch[100], var[100], val[100], tempVa[100];
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        puts("\nEnter the expression (or (end) to exit):");
        gets(ch);
        if (strcmp(ch, "end") == 0 || strcmp(ch, "END") == 0)
            return -1; // edit
        else if(2 == sscanf(ch, "%s = %s", var, val))
        {
            i = 0;
            printf("Variable is : %s\t Value Before evaluating : %s\n", var, val);
            while (i <= strlen(val))
            {
                while (val[i] != '-' && val[i] != '%' && val[i] != '/' && val[i] != '*' && val[i] != '+' && i < strlen(val))
                    tempVa[j++] = val[i++];

                i++;
                for (count = 0; count < strlen(tempVa); count++)
                    printf("%c", tempVa[count]);
                for (count = strlen(tempVa); count >= 0; count--)
                    tempVa[count] = '\0';
                j = 0;
            }
        }
        else
            printf("Invalid!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

> Enter the expression (or (end) to exit): Hassan = Merna+Mohamed+Ahmed
>   Variable is : Hassan     Value Before evaluating : Merna+Mohamed+Ahmed
>   MernaMohamedAhmed
>   Enter the expression (or (end) to exit):